# How to get Sender IP using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have been trying to get Sender IP from the response provided by the following :-

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADhAAAW-VPeAAA=/?$select=internetMessageHeaders`.

The response which I get has multiple `Receiver` tags as shown below :-

```
{
    "@odata.context":"<some-value>",
    "@odata.etag":"<some-value>",
    "id":"<some-value>",
    "internetMessageHeaders":[
        {
            "name":"MIME-Version",
            "value":"1.0"
        },
        {
            "name":"Content-Type",
            "value":"multipart/report"
        },
        {
            "name":"x-custom-header-group-name",
            "value":"Washington"
        },
        {
            "name":"x-custom-header-group-id",
            "value":"WA001"
        },
        {
            "name":"Receiver",
            "value":"<some-ip>"
        },
        {
            "name":"Receiver",
            "value":"<some-ip>"
        },

    ]
}
```

How do I get the actual origin Sender IP of the Mail using Graph API?

Is there any other way of getting the Sender IP using Graph API apart from the method mentioned above?

Comment: If you are looking at then refer [RFC5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) which defines what contents it needs to have in internetmessageheaders - i failed to see anything related to sender IP, the closest i see is that sender email address.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am interested in the Sender IP, I am unable to understand whether the first `Receiver` tag gives me origin or the last or is there any specific tag?

Comment: AFAIK i failed to find something on the same lines.

Comment: I did finally, in the `Authentication-Results` tag gives me `spf=pass (sender ip is<some-ip>),...` and finally wrote a regex to extract it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing it back. Make sure it works in all your scenario!! If yes, go ahead, convert as answer (in the below Your answer box) - so that it can be used by others in the community as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph API response looks something similar to the following and the `Authentication-Results` gives me the relevant origin Sender IP -

```
{
    "@odata.context":"<some-value>",
    "@odata.etag":"<some-value>",
    "id":"<some-value>",
    "internetMessageHeaders":[
        {
            "name":"MIME-Version",
            "value":"1.0"
        },
        {
            "name":"Content-Type",
            "value":"multipart/report"
        },
        {
            "name":"x-custom-header-group-name",
            "value":"Washington"
        },
        {
            "name":"x-custom-header-group-id",
            "value":"WA001"
        },
        {
            "name":"Receiver",
            "value":"<some-ip>"
        },
        {
            "name":"Receiver",
            "value":"<some-ip>"
        },
        {
            "name":"Authentication-Results",
            "value":"spf=pass (sender ip is <some-ip>)...,"       
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, all you need is a regex to extract -

1. Get the value present in `Authentication-Results`
2. Use the Regex - `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` to extract IP, use the first occurence of the match with regex.